# Get Id and data from database and add to JCombobox

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jcombobox, comboboxmodel

I want to get name and id from database and add it to `JCombobox`. For this i used

```
       public void add_Category(JComboBox cmb) {

       try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {

                String Txtcmb = rs.getString(2).trim();
                int idCmb = rs.getInt("id");
                Item comboItem = new Item(idCmb, Txtcmb); 
                cmb.addItem(comboitem);   //This line add only 1 object in combocox but i have 5 in my database
           }
       } catch(Exception e) {

       }
   }
```

Item.java

```
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private String description;

    public Item(int id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when I add object into combobox it add only one object while I have 5  object into my database.

It display me only one item in combobox instead of 5. One more thing i want to clear if I add only string into database like `comboItem.addItem(Txtcmb);` then it works fine

Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only reason it would only be adding is because there's only one item coming from the database...or some error occurred while processing the second item, but since you've ignored the exception you wouldn't know

Comment: Try to print the `idCmb` and `Txtcmb` and see how many result you got in your resultset.

Comment: model for JComboBox should be based on Item (incomplete), have to tell ListCellRenderer that to display description (missing there), then selection from JComboBox returns ID, for best of code with good explanation to search in posts by @camickr (tagged by JComboBox)

Comment: as aside then is possible to display two same Item in JComboBox and selection returns proper coordinates d form model, otherwise (bug in DeafultComboBoxModel) isn't possible, selection returns last or near index

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. Actually i was using Item comboItem[]; before while and and Item comboItem = new Item(idCmb, Txtcmb); inside while. When i remove Item comboItem[]; line and clean and buid my project again then it start working. Again thanks for your concern.